# C# Visual Studio GUI designing

Tags: c#, user-interface, visual-studio-2012

I've created a gui in visual studio with a nice ribbon. Now I want to fill the main form with different panels. I can just use panels, place all items on it and call them to the front when needed. This would solve my problems. It is actually very hard to maintain those pannels when programming. I was wondering, is there a good option to create panels above each other which I can maintain easily?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: could you elaborate w/ code or screenshots?

Comment: Do you actually mean [Dockable windows](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/623e217e-cec7-4957-b0fb-c4f3c7bb9980/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve this using `Form.MdiParent`  property. 

you can follow below links for more information.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4dabts7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3553/Introduction-to-MDI-Forms-with-C

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to create each panel as a separate UserControl.  This would then let you easily see the contents at design time without having to bring to the front all the time.